# Is it possible to get the date/time a user followed another using the Soundcloud API?

Tags: api, soundcloud

I'm going thru the logged-in user's followings and want to know when they followed each of those other users. Is that information available? If so, how do I access it? (FWIW, I'm using the python version of the API, although I assume the answer would be easily translatable to any supported language).

Comment: If that information is available it should be in their docs: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs

Comment: Believe me, I've been poring over the docs. Many things are not clear, though!

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint should be **me/activities** and the result looks like this, with a created_at field:

```
{"collection":[{"uuid":"16f5a800-651a-11e3-8015-ce245d766b44","type":"track-like","created_at":"2013/12/14 23:47:28 +0000","tags":"own","track":{"kind":"track","id":30984358,"created_at":"2011/12/18 20:41:54 +0000","user_id":1672444,"duration":192465,"commentable":true,"state":"finished","original_content_size":73848028,"sharing":"public","tag_list":"ABC \"Jackson 5\" MIchael Jackson Edit Remix Oldschool Dance House Funk house techhouse bootleg \"free download\"","permalink":"abc-bnz-edit","streamable":true,"embeddable_by":"all","downloadable":false,"purchase_url":null,"label_id":null,"purchase_title":null,"genre":"House","title":"Jackson Five - ABC (bnz edit)","description":"","label_name":"","release":"","track_type":"remix","key_signature":"","isrc":"","video_url":null,"bpm":null,"release_year":null,"release_month":null,"release_day":null,"original_format":"wav","license":"all-rights-reserved","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/30984358","user":{"id":1672444,"kind":"user","permalink":"bnzlovesyou","username":"bnz x live","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/1672444","permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/bnzlovesyou","avatar_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000045663574-d4prxh-large.jpg?d53bf9f"},"user_playback_count":1,"user_favorite":false,"permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/bnzlovesyou/abc-bnz-edit","artwork_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000015546673-voy071-large.jpg?d53bf9f","waveform_url":"https://w1.sndcdn.com/gfE7Wrcio9TB_m.png","stream_url":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/30984358/stream","download_url":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/30984358/download","playback_count":1565,"download_count":100,"favoritings_count":18,"comment_count":1,"likes_count":18,"reposts_count":2,"attachments_uri":"https://api. ... [...]
```

You are looking for affiliations:

```
{"uuid":"cee8f400-551e-11e3-80c2-a6bc93c4098d","type":"affiliation","created_at":"2013/11/24 15:40:56 +0000","tags":"own","user":{"id":67807714,"kind":"user","permalink":"captureyourown","username":"captureYouRown","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/67807714","permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/captureyourown","avatar_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000061206183-d3koqu-large.jpg?d53bf9f","country":"Belgium","full_name":"c.","description":null,"city":"BRUXELLES","discogs_name":null,"myspace_name":null,"website":null,"website_title":null,"online":false,"track_count":0,"playlist_count":0,"plan":"Free","public_favorites_count":16,"followers_count":37,"followings_count":311,"subscriptions":[],"likes_count":16,"reposts_count":7,"comments_count":0}}
```

Comment: I read a quarter million records from me/activities using my own account and the only "type" values I see are "playlist", "playlist-sharing", "track", and "track-sharing". The earliest record has a created_at timestamp on 2013/12/17 and I know I have followed several other soundclouders more recently than that.